# How to integrate a user control that uses the Webservice to display data in DNN?

Tags: user-controls, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I have one user control that fetches the data from one web-service.

I want to keep that user control intact and want to deploy (Integrate) the same within DNN 6.1.2 so how can i do that?

Please note that I am new to DNN and aware little about DNN terminology; so hope the question is self explanatory.

Let me know the steps for the same.

Comment: Not sure if l understand the question, can you give any specific details?

Comment: Please do not write footers in all of your questions and answers with your email address in them. That is not allowed here.

Comment: @BobF :- My question is that how can I deploy user control in DNN? (We can do this very simply in Umbraco; I want to know how to do the same in DNN?) Let's say my usercontrol is fetching data from WS and works fine in my .Net based website pages; now I have DNN Site and I want to deploy the same user control in that DNN site's page. So how can we do that?

Comment: @Brad Larson :- I will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to host->extensions, click the manage button then select create new module.

Comment: yes but after that what? Should i select the user control and put the user control DLL in Bin.. that's it? Please provide step by step guide if possiable